# Regex - matching only a single character

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, matcher

I need to find a match over the following text and I need to detect only one single under score by using REGEX:

Text: `network_ip__c`

Result: true

Text: `Opportunity__c`

Result: false

How can I accomplish this requirement in APEX?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more? Do you want to find underscore only? Or anything that is between underscores?

Comment: I need to find only one instance of underscore, for example, 
network_ip__c = true, Opportunity__c = false

Comment: There are a lot of sites that will help you with regex syntax, such as https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
_[^_c]
```

This searches for _ that is not followed by _c

Try it here: https://regex101.com/

[image]

You can test it this way:

```
String test1 = 'Opportunity__c';
String test2 = 'Opportunity_abc__c';
String regex = '_[^_c]';

System.debug(test1.split(regex).size() != 1); // false
System.debug(test2.split(regex).size() != 1); // true
```

This may be a bit wierd, but if string does not contain regex, it will not be split (1 element as result) and if it contains, it will have at least 2 elements.

Comment: what if you wanted to omit the c ? i.e get only the _ part

Answer (score 1):

If you do  not need regex you could simply do:

```
[string].replace('__','').contains('_');
```

If you are in Apex Not sure that regex would be required but that is up to you.

The regex (match all single non repeated occurrences of the character) would be: `(?<!_)_(?!_)` and will need to be adjusted for Apex.

Comment: How can we calculate the CPU time even? Is there any specific metrics to use?

Comment: Throw the code in a loop (size of your choosing, maybe 1000) with debug statements of the CPU time before and after the loop and output the difference. Do several times and take average

Comment: Does the internet connection plays any role in this calculation?

Comment: No.............

Comment: Sounds good. I will make a note of this. Very helpful.